# Spring MVC - HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

Okay, I'm having this problem when I'm running my application and I believe it is because of the versioning.

First of Fall, I'm using Tomcat 9.0.4.
And I'm using the latest Java SDK.

Now, I'm using the Spring version 5.0.2.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mvctest</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstMvcApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xli="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xli:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>FirstMvcApp</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And this is my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-5.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/spring-mvc-5.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/spring-context-5.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.firstwebapp.controllers" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Now, I do want to mention something: See those `/spring-**-5.0.xsd` in the dispatcher-servlet? I'm not sure if that's right.
Why? Well, this is the error that I'm getting in the output:

```
C:\JavaWebServers\apache-tomcat-9.0.4\bin\catalina.bat run
[2018-02-01 10:38:56,961] Artifact FirstMvcApp:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\germmand\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_FirstMvcApp"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\JavaWebServers\apache-tomcat-9.0.4"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\JavaWebServers\apache-tomcat-9.0.4\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\JavaWebServers\apache-tomcat-9.0.4\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\JavaWebServers\apache-tomcat-9.0.4\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.042 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.4
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.044 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jan 18 2018 19:42:17 UTC
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.044 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.4.0
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.044 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.044 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.044 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.044 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.046 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           9.0.1+11
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.046 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.047 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\germmand\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_FirstMvcApp
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.047 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\JavaWebServers\apache-tomcat-9.0.4
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.048 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.048 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.048 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\germmand\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_FirstMvcApp\conf\logging.properties
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.048 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.048 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.048 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.048 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.050 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.050 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.050 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.050 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.050 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.050 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\germmand\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_FirstMvcApp
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.051 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\JavaWebServers\apache-tomcat-9.0.4
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.051 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\JavaWebServers\apache-tomcat-9.0.4\temp
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.051 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\germmand\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\germmand\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;.]
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.091 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.106 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.113 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.115 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.115 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 445 ms
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.174 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Arrancando servicio [Catalina]
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.175 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.4
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.182 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.191 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
01-Feb-2018 22:38:58.195 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 79 ms
Connected to server
[2018-02-01 10:38:58,540] Artifact FirstMvcApp:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
01-Feb-2018 22:38:59.902 INFORMACIÓN [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars Al menos un JAR, que se ha explorado buscando TLDs, aún no contenía TLDs. Activar historial de depuración para este historiador para una completa lista de los JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se halló TLDs. Saltarse JARs no necesarios durante la exploración puede dar lugar a una mejora de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilación de JSP .
01-Feb-2018 22:39:00.172 INFORMACIÓN [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
01-Feb-2018 22:39:00.216 INFORMACIÓN [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Feb 01 22:39:00 VET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
01-Feb-2018 22:39:00.282 INFORMACIÓN [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
01-Feb-2018 22:39:01.106 ADVERTENCIA [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.util.xml.SimpleSaxErrorHandler.warning Ignored XML validation warning
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 137; schema_reference.4: Fallo al leer el documento de esquema 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-5.0.xsd', porque 1) no se ha encontrado el documento; 2) no se ha podido leer el documento; 3) el elemento raíz del documento no es <xsd:schema>.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:391)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:305)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4207)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(XSDHandler.java:4198)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(XSDHandler.java:2512)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2210)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:584)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:619)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2709)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2068)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:828)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3058)
    AND GOES ON...
```

Now, I know that's a huge chunk of text and you probably won't read it. 
The problem starts here:

```
org.springframework.util.xml.SimpleSaxErrorHandler.warning Ignored XML validation warning
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 137; schema_reference.4: Fallo al leer el documento de esquema 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-5.0.xsd', porque 1) no se ha encontrado el documento; 2) no se ha podido leer el documento; 3) el elemento raíz del documento no es <xsd:schema>.
```

Which translated to english says something like:
'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-5.0.xsd' either couldn't be found, or couldn't be read, ot the root of the document isn't 'xsd:schema'.

And this is a pic of what I get in the browser:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Include following maven dependency in the pom.xml

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I added those dependencies but still getting the same error.

Comment: don't use version instead use like 
 `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/spring-mvc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/spring-context.xsd">
`

Comment: I did. But it says that `http://www.springframework.org/schema/spring-context.xsd` couldn't be found.